# Strong convergence of differential quotient in $L^2(0,T;V^*)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, approximation-theory

I have got a problem regarding the weak differentiability of Bochner-integrable functions. Let $(V,H,V^*)$ be a Gelfand-triple and 
\begin{align*}
w \in W(0,T) := \{w\in L^2(0,T;V) ~\vert~ \exists w' \in L^2(0,T;V^*) \}.
\end{align*}
We know $w$ is equal to a continuous function in $H$. Does the differential quotient converge in $L^2(0,T;V^*)$, namely 
\begin{align*}
\frac{w(t+h) - w(t)}{h} \to w'(t) \text{ in } L^2(0,T;V^*)?
\end{align*}
I need this result to prove the convergence of an implicit Euler scheme.

Thanks you, FFoDWindow

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that $w'$ for you indicates $dw/dt$. From your formula it seems that you want strong convergence of the difference quotient, correct?

At the moment I don't see that you have the necessary time regularity to prove such a statement. You know at the moment only that $w$ and $w'$ are square-integrable in time, and a simple continuity in time is not enough. Can you prove absolute continuity?

Comment: Hey Kira, thank you for your reply. It should be absoluly continuous in $L^2(0,T;V^*)$, since $V,H,V^*$ form a Gelfand-Triple. I'll verify it tomorrow.

Comment: Our $w$ is absolutely continuous with values in $V^*$.

Comment: @FFoDWindow Did you take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/980049/10311 (which in turn refers to Evans, section 5.8.2)

Comment: @anonymous: What you are referring to is the situation for real-valued functions. The question of FFoDWindow was about Banach-space-valued functions. The book of Evans has here some limited material in Chapter 7, however not for the question asked.

Comment: @KiraG. Fair enough. The equivalence between $p$-integrability of the gradient and difference quotients of a vector-valued $L^p(0,T,X)$ function can e.g. be found as Theorem 3.20 in [M. Kreuter's master thesis](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.020/abschlussarbeiten/MA_Marcel_Kreuter.pdf) (assuming that $X$ has the Radon-Nikodým property).